# How to read video metadata (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, video, taglib

I am trying to write a small music manager in Linux using C++. I am currently using TagLib to read the media's metadata. However, as far as I know, TagLib does not support reading tags (title, artist, etc...) from a video. Therefore, I just want to ask you guys if there is any other library I can use to read the tags (title, artist, etc...) of a video file?

Thank you for answering my question! You guys have a good week!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/tr) library

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I knew this library but I could not find any example of how to use MediaInfo to read video tags. The example in the source code is aimed at DLL, and I am developing my software running on Linux. Do you have any decent MediaInfo example?

Comment: If you look at download section you can see linux compatible packages. BTW I am using it with Java on Windows when I finish I will port to linux also. When you download with source code there are lots of examples for all supported languages (C++,Java,C# etc)